# Jquery send Json data not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to sent some JSON data with ajax this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jsonObj = [];
    $('.img-bg').map(function () {
        var self = this;
        var next = $(this).nextAll('.rectangle');

        if (next.length > 0) {
            next.map(function () {
                item = {};
                item.src = self.src;
                item.left = $(this).css('left');
                item.height = $(this).css('height');

                jsonObj.push(item);
            });
        }


});
var data={ "firstName" : "Ray" };
jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);


        $.ajax({
            url: 'testajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonString,
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);

            }

        });

    });


</script>
```

And `jsonObj` gives

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
height: "341px"
left: "10px"
src: "http://localhost/docAuto/test.jpg"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
height: "321px"
left: "54px"
src: "http://localhost/docAuto/image.jpg"
```

Output of jsonString

```
[{"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/test.jpg","left":"10px","height":"341px"},
{"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/image.jpg","left":"54px","height":"321px"},
{"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/image.jpg","left":"43px","height":"295px"}]
```

Both var is not send, but if I send `data` it's working. My Json file is wrong?

Comment: I check code- it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the options to `data` as an object. Here's a fixed `$.ajax` call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'testajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { json : jsonString },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Your `testajax.php` should now see the jsonString in URL variable `json`.

edit: fixed my response. I misread your code due to the problems with indentation.

Comment: Yes It's my actual code if I move `jsonObj = [];` out from `$(document).ready()`  it's still not working

Comment: Sorry. I misread your code initially, and thought `$.ajax()` was outside `$(document).ready()`. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: This should work, but why convert the json object to a string, and then put it back into an object? Why not just pass the original object as your data parameter?

Comment: I believe depending on the jQuery version an array of objects might not be encoded properly to a query string. Also different backends handle such query strings (a[0]=1&a[1]=2) differently. It's always safe to pass an encoded JSON string and let the backend handle decoding and JSON to Object mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` to send a json object via the jQuery `$.ajax()` method... jQuery will take care of that conversion behind the scenes. Just use jsonObj as your data parameter.

Comment: You *do* need to use `JSON.stringify` to send JSON. If you pass a JavaScript object to `data` then it will covert it to form encoded data, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `POST` in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON is missing the key part. When I added the key: 'first', it worked. You got one mighty Json Array there:

```
JSON.stringify({ first: [{"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/test.jpg","left":"10px","height":"341px"},
 {"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/image.jpg","left":"54px","height":"321px"},
 {"src":"http://localhost/docAuto/image.jpg","left":"43px","height":"295px"}] })
```

[JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/suvG7/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/suvG7/1/)

[Json Arrays, syntax etc link](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)